# npm install doesnt create the node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, npm-install

I've been trying to make a canvas project on discord.js but I can't npm install to work properly it just installs it to my appdata folder. I'd be happy if you could help me figure it out

Comment: do you have package.json already present in your path? Can you post the content?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `npm init` in a terminal?

If not here are the steps to follow:

1. Open a terminal/command window in the directory you want to store the file in it
2. Run `npm init`
3. Fill in the project data
4. Run `npm install [PACKAGE_NAME]`

Comment: I did i tried everything that i can think of

Comment: @Cookie can you post the command you used? is there global or -g used in it?

Comment: nope I just did npm install discord.js and npm install canvas

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute npm init -y in your project folder which then creates the necessary files for installing modules.